# How many connections will open in mongodb in python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am working with mongodb and python, for accessing the database I am doing  this:

```
#pymongo connection settings
from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['MyDB']
```

I am inserting documents like this:

```
db_data = db.mycollection.insert({'name': 'Mulagala', 'age': 24})
```

and finding like this:

```
db_data = db.mycollection.find()
```

When I am creating multiple users or getting `mycollection` details for multiple times how many conections will open in mongodb. Do I need to close any open connection before returning result?

Answer (score 2):

No matter how many `db.coll.find({...})` and `db.coll.insert({...})` will you do, you will still have only one connection. You do not need to close open connection (at the end of the script it will be closed automatically)

**P.S.** `MongoClient` is the preferred method to [connect to mongo](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html) (`Connection` is deprecated)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you reference the source of your information?

Comment: @PierrePrinetti which part of information do you need source for?

Comment: I wonder if the fact that pymongo only opens a single connection to the server is documented anywhere. A reference could be useful in case this behaviour changes in a next version.

Comment: @PierrePrinetti in the question, OP asks whether the find and insert increases the number of connections and if you will look at documentation in never tells that it does so (it would be quite inefficient to open a new connection for each insert/update/find).

Comment: It is all documented here in detail: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo